# Substitute pattern matching of trait implementors with enum_dispatch

Tags: rust

According to this article "[Don't use boxed trait objects for struct internals](https://bennetthardwick.com/dont-use-boxed-trait-objects-for-struct-internals)", it's a bad idea to store trait objects in a struct field because we loose valuable type information about our objects. So they propose creating an enum wrapper for all of our trait implementers.

In the below example, `trait Person` has implementers `struct Me` and `struct Grandma`, and we want to store both kinds of these implementers inside `struct PeopleZoo.people`.

But because we want to preserve type information about our implementers in the `PeopleZoo.people` field, we create a wrapper enum `Person`, instead of using `Box<dyn Person>`:

```rust
//our common trait
trait Person {
    fn say_hello(&self);
}
//trait implementor 1
struct Me {
    name: &'static str,
}

impl Person for Me {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello, it's me.")
    }
}

struct Grandma {
    age: usize
}

impl Person for Grandma {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("G'day!")
    }
}

enum People {
    Grandma(Grandma),
    Me(Me)
}
//tedious pattern matching statement
impl Person for People {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        match self {
            People::Grandma(grandma) => grandma.say_hello(),
            People::Me(me) => me.say_hello()
        }
    }
}

struct PeopleZoo<P: Person> {
    people: Vec<P>,
}

impl<P: Person> PeopleZoo<P> {
    fn add_person(&mut self, person: P) {
        self.people.push(person);
    }

    fn last_person(&self) -> Option<&P> {
        self.people.last()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut zoo: PeopleZoo<People> = PeopleZoo { people: vec![] };
    zoo.add_person(People::Me(Me { name: "Bennett" }));
    
    if let Some(People::Me(me)) = zoo.last_person() {
        println!("My name is {}.", me.name)
    }
}
```

The problem is that writing the pattern matching syntax for all of our trait functions for `Person` can become rather tedious. As I understand it [enum_dispatch](https://docs.rs/enum_dispatch/0.3.7/enum_dispatch/) will do some of this pattern matching work for us, and auto-implement `Person for People`. But I'm not exactly sure how to get it to work.

```rust
use enum_dispatch::enum_dispatch;

#[enum_dispatch(Person)]
trait Person {
    fn say_hello(&self);
}
//implementor struct 1
struct Me {
    name: &'static str,
}

impl Person for Me {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("Hello, it's me.")
    }
}
//implementor struct 2
struct Grandma {
    age: usize
}

impl Person for Grandma {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        println!("G'day!")
    }
}

#[enum_dispatch]
enum People {
    Grandma(Grandma),
    Me(Me)
}
//I thought enum_dispatch generated this impl for us automatically, so comment out
//impl Person for People {
//    fn say_hello(&self) {
//        match self {
//           People::Grandma(grandma) => grandma.say_hello(),
//            People::Me(me) => me.say_hello()
//        }
//    }
//}

struct PeopleZoo<P: Person> {
    people: Vec<P>,
}

impl<P: Person> PeopleZoo<P> {
    fn add_person(&mut self, person: P) {
        self.people.push(person);
    }

    fn last_person(&self) -> Option<&P> {
        self.people.last()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut zoo: PeopleZoo<People> = PeopleZoo { people: vec![] };
    zoo.add_person(People::Me(Me { name: "Bennett" }));
    
    if let Some(People::Me(me)) = zoo.last_person() {
        println!("My name is {}.", me.name)
    }
}
```

gives error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `last_person` exists for struct `PeopleZoo<People>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src\main.rs:63:39
   |
30 | enum People {
   | ----------- doesn't satisfy `People: Person`
...
44 | struct PeopleZoo<P: Person> {
   | --------------------------- method `last_person` not found for this
...
63 |     if let Some(People::Me(me)) = zoo.last_person() {
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `PeopleZoo<People>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
   |
   = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `People: Person`
```

Am I understanding enum_dispatch's functionality correctly? If so how might I get this example to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing

```rust
#[enum_dispatch(Person)]
trait Person {
    fn say_hello(&self);
}
```

to

```rust
#[enum_dispatch(People)]
trait Person {
    fn say_hello(&self);
}
```

and the code works as expected. I needed to pass our wrapper enum into the `enum_dispatch` attribute for our `Person` trait.